# How to run methods of inner object in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have `Inner` class which has two methods `get_value`, `set_value` and property `value` with default meaning of those. Now I have class `Outer` which creates objects of other classes (like `Inner`) and assign them as its attribute:

```py
class Outer:
    def __init__(self, configuration: int):
        if configuration == 1:
            self.inner = Inner("Some data")
            self.other = Other("Some data")
        elif ...
        else:
            self.inner = Inner("Some data")
            self.other = Other("Some data")
```

(There will always be `inner`, `other`). I would like to use `Outer.inner.Get Value` and `Outer.inner.Set Value  ${3}` inside Robot Framework test. How to do it?

This is what I came up with (using "Extended variable syntax"):

- I added `get_inner` method to `Outer` class that returns `self.inner`.
- Assign `inner` object to new variable `${MyVar}` in RF.
- Then use `${MyVar.get_value()}`

However with this approach I cannot just call a method without assigning it anywhere (can't call setter):

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Path.To.Outer  ${1}  WITH NAME  Out

*** Test Cases ***
Check setting current
    ${MyVar}  Out.Get Inner
    ${Initial Value}  Set Variable  ${MyVar.get_value()}
    ${New Value}  Evaluate  ${Initial Value}+${1}
    ${PS.set_current(3)}  # This is not working
```

`get_value` worked but in fourth line of code I get `Keyword name cannot be empty.` error. In fact my goal is to use `${New Value}` there instead of hardcoded value, like  `${PS.set_current(${New Value})}`. How should I fix my code?